# Create a random number between -100 and 100 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, random, range, negative-number

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating random numbers in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript)

I have the following code `var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*101);` that generates a random number for me between 1 and 100. What I would like to do is generate a random number between -100 and 100. I am not sure what to do exactly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could start by reading your Javascript function reference.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

First, generate a random number between 1 - 200 then subtract 100:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 201) - 100;
```

Comment: +1 was just writing the same answer..

Comment: Quick question: Can Math.floor() return a value that falls inside [0.99999999999999995, 0.99999999999999999]. Because if it can then the result will be 101 which is outside the given bounds (at least that's what I surmised by running tests on the chrome console). Of course it's a small chance for such a corner case to actually take place (near hardware error). But still its eerie.

Comment: How about "a + Math.floor(Math.random() * (b – a))" <- this seems more concise.

Answer (score -3):

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*200)-100;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 201 to include 100?